# "How to we categorize appropriation"

Tags: meaning, infinitives, syntactic-analysis

I cannot grasp the sentence structure of this:

> What incites my curiosity even further is **how to** we categorize appropriation in the case when Japanese people say that there is nothing offensive about an “appropriation”, that they are not victimized, but are, instead happy? ([Source](https://japanincanada.com/ariana-grandes-tattoo/))

What makes me confused is the part of **"how to"**. I understand the subject is `What incites my curiosity even further`, but why does "`we categorize` "come after "`to`", not a verb, just "`categorize`"?

Then it occurred to me that maybe I grasped the structure wrongly. Or is it just a mistake?

Comment: It's an error, possibly a typo.

Comment: Sounds like the writer was debating "how do we categorize" and "how to categorize" and didn't clean up after making the decision.

Comment: The article this is taken from is badly written and riddled with mistakes.  Moreover, it liberally quotes Tweets that are themselves carelessly written.  While I understand that it's sometimes necessary to read material that's badly written, I think that someone who is learning English should try to read high-quality, well-written material as much as possible.  By reading good writing, you will develop a sense over time of what is correct and standard and what is not.

Answer (score -1):

The original has some convoluted syntax a statement that slowly converts to a question. I suspect the sentence should read:

> What incites my curiosity ... is how **do** we categorize appropriation...?

or even

> What incites my curiosity ... is how  we categorize appropriation... .

(where the latter is a statement of the thing that incites curiosity, rather than a question).

Comment: Even if it's meant to be a question, it should be "What incites my curiosity is the question of how we categorize appropriation."  I don't believe it is ever correct in standard English to invert the subject and verb in an embedded question.  See: https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/inversion-embedded-questions.

Comment: Or *how to categorize...*

Comment: @hguler TRomano, yes to both. Probably better than mine.

Comment: @hguler: When it's like the following it's grammatical (although informal):  *What incites my curiosity is, how do we ...?* It's like *What I want to know is, when's lunch?*

Comment: @TRomano Unquote all those and I'm in.

Comment: @TRomano: I agree, but it's colloquial, and the comma is important.  Your examples are short for "What incites my curiosity is, 'How do we ...?'" and "What I want to know is, 'When's lunch?'"  The quotation marks are dropped only because it's clear from the context that what follows the comma is a quoted question.